Error compiling Rust library with OpenSSL dependency for Android (x86_64-linux-android target)
I'm working on an Android app built with Kotlin in Android Studio, and I'm trying to integrate a Rust library into my project. The Rust library has a dependency on OpenSSL. When I attempt to compile the Rust library with the x86_64-linux-android target, I encounter the following error:
error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.17.8`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:<PROJECT-PATH>\app\src\main\rust\target\debug\build\ring-52324e4519f4905a\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=RING_PREGENERATE_ASM
  cargo:rustc-env=RING_CORE_PREFIX=ring_core_0_17_8_
  OPT_LEVEL = Some(0)
  TARGET = Some(x86_64-linux-android)
  OUT_DIR = Some(C:<PROJECT-PATH>\app\src\main\rust\target\x86_64-linux-android\debug\build\ring-ae4372e2a1fc0bf3\out)
  HOST = Some(x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-linux-android
  CC_x86_64-linux-android = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_linux_android
  CC_x86_64_linux_android = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CC
  TARGET_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_ENABLE_DEBUG_OUTPUT
  cargo:warning=Compiler family detection failed due to error: ToolNotFound: Failed to find tool. Is `x86_64-linux-android-clang` installed? (see https://github.com/rust-lang/cc-rs#compile-time-requirements for help)
  ...

The error seems to be related to the ring crate, which is a dependency of OpenSSL. The issue appears to be that the compiler cannot find the x86_64-linux-android-clang tool, which is required for compiling the ring crate for the x86_64-linux-android target.
If I remove the OpenSSL dependency from my Rust library, the compilation succeeds without any issues.
I've tried searching for solutions, but I haven't found a clear answer on how to resolve this issue. I'm using the following versions:

Cargo: 1.79.0
Rustup: 1.27.1
Android Studio: Koala
-- SDK 35
-- NDK 27 & 23
-- CMake 3.22.1
Kotlin: 1.8 / Java 17
LLVM 18.1.6

Question: How can I resolve this issue and successfully compile my Rust library with the OpenSSL dependency for the x86_64-linux-android target?
